# Is there a way to automate conversion of web app to iphone or android native app?

Tags: iphone

I came across this link:
http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596805784/
which seems to suggest web app can be converted to native iphone without writing a single line
of objective-c code. But the book mentioned there is outdated now and things may have changed a lot. 
Are there open source software that will allow me to automatically convert my web application to native iphone ( or android) application? By the way my web application is html5 canvas based animation application with lot of html and css as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) doesn't generate native code for you: it creates an application consisting of a WebView and throws your HTML code on it. From personal exerience I can add that the performance is quite slow, on both iPhone and Android, compared to a native app.
[jqTouch](http://jqtouch.com/) creates a nice way to access your web application, but the application remains a web application residing on your site, plus you have to use some jquery for styling.
Apparently the only one that actually does generate native code is [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/). On [RhoMobile](http://rhomobile.com/) I never managed to get to the point to actually write some Ruby code because you have to know all the Ruby in he word just to install it on your Mac.
So the verdict was to sit down and develop the app in objective-c.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I was just looking at Titanium and I had the same question about Titanium too which seemed to have the capability but so far my conclusion is that there is no framework or package that would convert html5 canvas code to native code.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/)?

Comment: I was just reading up on phonegap. Does phonegap automatically convert html5 canvas code to iphone native 2d drawing graphics api or phonegap is just a thin wrapper around my web application to make it make it look like native iphone app?

Answer (score 0):

Simple steps to put your html app into iOS native container, without coding:

- Download xCode
- Download simple web view app from https://github.com/nomtek/iOSWebViewApp
- Open simple web view app within xCode
- Add your HTMLs to the project file structure
- Run your app and voila :)

This approach is good if you don't need access to any phone specific features, just a standard Web View. Loading time will be short as this approach doesn't load any extra libraries.