# How can I deploy my web application as a native one on iPhone, Android, and Blackberry?

Tags: jquery, iphone, android, blackberry, installation

I have developed a HTML application which uses JQuery to get the data from webservice and the application is running fine. Now I want to depoy it on the phones like Blackberry, Android phones and iPhone.

Is there any way I can compile my HTML application is a package so that person can install it on their mobile (like other native applications)?

I am specific to these three phones only:

1. Android phones
2. iPhone
3. Blackberry

Comment: By the way, it’s “Android”, not “Andriod” ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to automate conversion of web app to iphone or android native app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775105/is-there-a-way-to-automate-conversion-of-web-app-to-iphone-or-android-native-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phonegap, titanium, or use a web-app.

Comment: Will phonegap has a method to prepare exe or something which I can provide to the end user ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out phonegap (http://www.phonegap.com/)

Comment: Will it work on Windows Server 2008 or XP ?? Because when I downloaded it is showing me _MACOSX folder. Also, how could I compile and make a installation exe with it. Any help!